# i want to append every text in <p> that i write in contenteditable div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

i want to append every text in `<p>` and table in a `div` that i write in contenteditable div
means when i start write in `<div contenteditable="true">` it dynamically add it in a paragraph `<p>`.
i solved the `<table>` problem ,now its in `<div>`   but not every text that i write

example

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>heloo this is first paragraph</p>
<p>this is second paragraph</p>
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td> name</td>
   <td> age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> john</td>
   <td> 32</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<p>this is third paragraph</p>

<p>this is fourth paragraph </p>
</div>
```

html code

```
<div contentditable="true" id="result"></div>
            <input   id="numofrows" placeholder="no. of rows" />
            <input  id="numofcols" placeholder="no. of cols" />

            <button type="button" onclick="createTable()" class="tbrow" id="tableGen">create</button>
```

javascript code

```
var result = document.getElementById("result")
var generateRows = document.getElementById('numofrows')
var generateCols = document.getElementById('numofcols')

result.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
        return false;
    }
var bodyText = document.querySelector('#result');
  var pNode = document.createElement('p');
  var firstLine = bodyText.firstChild;
  pNode.appendChild(firstLine);
  bodyText.prepend(pNode);
});
function createTable(rw, cl) {
  //create div
  var divTableNode = document.createElement('div');
  var newRandomIdDIv = "newdiv" + Math.random(); //create unique id for div
  divTableNode.setAttribute(`Id`,`${newRandomIdDIv}`) //set an attribute of id unique in the div
  var tableNode = document.createElement("table")
    tableNode.classList.add('table')
    var newRandomIdDIv = "mewtablediv" + Math.random() + ""; 
   tableNode.setAttribute(`Id`,` ${newRandomIdDIv}  `)
   divTableNode.appendChild(tableNode);
  for (var r = 1; r <= rw; r++) {
    var trNode = document.createElement("tr");
    var newRandomIdDIv = "newtrdiv" + Math.random() + ""; 
    trNode.setAttribute(`Id`,` ${newRandomIdDIv}  `)
    divTableNode.appendChild(tableNode);
    tableNode.appendChild(trNode);
    for (var i = 1; i <= cl; i++) {
      var tdNode = document.createElement("td");
      tdNode.setAttribute(`class`,`col`) 
      tdNode.innerHTML = `cols ${i} `;
      trNode.appendChild(tdNode);
      tableNode.appendChild(trNode);
      divTableNode.appendChild(tableNode);
    }
  }
  return divTableNode.outerHTML
}

tableGen.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var rows = parseInt(generateRows.value)//generateRows.valueAsNumber
  var cols = parseInt(generateCols.value)//generateCols.valueAsNumber
  var table = createTable(rows, cols);
  var bodyTextNode = result.textContent;
   var sel = document.getSelection();
   rng = sel.getRangeAt(0)
   //var start = rng.startOffset;
   var end = rng.endOffset;
  //result.innerHTML = table
  
  result.innerHTML = bodyTextNode.slice(end) + table
})
```

Comment: can you provide the javascript code you have tried?

Comment: i added javascript code please check @Tibebes.M